# SessionState Expired File does not exist c#

Tags: c#, .net, session-state

I have a webpage that uses web forms and uses `sessionstate` that is `cookieless`. Since it is `cookieless` the session is put in the url. The problem occurs when a user copy and pastes our url and tries to access their page after the `sessionstate` expires. Instead of the .net recreating a session or redirecting to a new session, I am getting the following error: The file (s(13vd3ucbiprwc0b2m5d3gfvu))/page.aspx' does not exist.

As you can see it looks like iis is looking for the actual file instead of realizing that there is a session in the url. I saw the following article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx and did check iis for the correct aspnet_filter.dll's and they are listed properly.

This is how I call the session state in the web config, please note I removed the database connection for security purposes:

```
sessionState mode="SQLServer" timeout="60" cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
```

Please note that is only one page and the users session is created on the `page_init`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue and want to answer this for anyone else having the same issue. The session in my url would look like, (S(13vd3ucbiprwc0b2m5d3gfvu)), but yet users were some how getting this, (s(13vd3ucbiprwc0b2m5d3gfvu)). If you notice the only difference is the S is uppercase in the normal link and the problematic links had a lowercase s. There were 2 simple fixes for this, in the global I just wrote some code that would redirect to the page again with an uppercase S. You could also use the iis rewrite tool to look for the lowercase s in the session and rewrite to an uppercase